# how to call getExtra() without getIntent() in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I want to `getExtra()` without the use of `getIntent()`.
Is this possible?
If yes, then how?

Comment: You need an Intent to be able to get the extra's off it :-)

Comment: yes,PutExtra() through put code get in getExtra() but without use getIntent()

Comment: but why are you afraid to call `getIntent()`?

Comment: no, but when I call in getExtra() method that java file is extends Service, and getIntent() is not call over there, so that's why I need whithout getIntent() use getExtra() method.

Answer (score 2):

No, its not possible to `getExtra()` without `getIntent()`

because without intent how can we passed data i mean `.putExtra()` ? and then you want to `getExtra()`

Comment: More importantly you need to have Bundle object of that intent, which is the real handler of extra datas.